# Generation of internal and external versions form MS-Word

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, xml, tags

I have in my organization some reports, where we want to keep an internal version including all paragraphs, but we need also to publish an external version, where the user can exclude paragraph by paragraph sections from the publication. 
I see some solutions, but have no clue which one should be followed, has someone more solved the same problem?

- Document structured tags could be used to generate 2 different PDFs from the single source file

  - Using XML structures
  - Using different Headings for paragraphs
    ...

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar requirement and the solution was to use different styles for internal and external content. The internal styles are set as hidden (under font settings) so they are visible on screen but not when printing to PDF or paper. Just make sure the "Print hidden text" option (Word options, under Display) isn't checked.

You can also define keyboard shortcuts for these internal styles so you can apply them quickly while going through the document. And for occasional hiding of some text you can create a character style (as opposed to a paragraph style) set to hidden, give it a keyboard shortcut, and you can mark any text and quickly hide it.